# NFS HEAT Back ground font

Tags: font-identification

Hi I need help with this font. I can't identify this BUSTED Font from NFS Heat. I need to recreate it. Could you help me with ID this font? Sending a link to a busted animation. I'm looking the font name or something very close to it.

Thank you for help and have a nice day :)

10:15
https://youtu.be/vEzkozQxKA8?t=610

Comment: Font identification websites like this https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/built-titling would show the right one quickly. Try it yourself. Limitation: Generally they find only what they sell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [FF DIN Std Condensed Black Italic](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-din/ot-cond-black-ita/) is pretty darn close myself:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ^w^ I am an artist on FA and need to know this to draw my own NFS Heat busted scene in Furry version XD thank you so much and Mary Christmas if you celebrate :)